# Tabular error "Missing $ inserted" with springer format

Tags: tables, errors

Please, how can I fix this error?

Missing $ inserted.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Different datasets with its sizes, types, ADF test, and compression ratio. }
\label{tabadf}
%\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
%\small
\scalebox{0.5}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|cccccc|c|c|}
\hline
Dataset               & Data type & Dataset size &  test   & A\_value  & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Critial DATA}                                                                                                                              & Result:        & Comunic \\ \hline
A                     & Int 32    & 3000         & -767 & 5.04\times 10^{-10}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-87.7} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-2.864} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10\%} & -1.518  & Stat_da     & 14.72       \\ \hline
B                     & Int 32    & 4000         & -34.304 & 3.94\times 10^{-13}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-3.4} & 

\end{tabular}}
%\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `5.04\times 10^{-10`}  is math so should be `$5.04\times 10^{-10} $ `

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle!

Comment: Also, there's `Stat_da`.  And don't use `\scalebox` or `adjustbox` on a table.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/107497 for options.

Answer (score 1):

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which can be compiled as it is.
- Your problem (s) are solved by comments.
- Don't scale table. This lead to inconsistent font size in table. Rather reduce `\tabcolsep` size and font size used in table.
- In your table I would use `S` columns types for aligning numbers at decimal points and avoid problem with writing number, which cause errors in your table.
- For table I would instead of `tabular` rather use `tblr` of `tabularray` package.
- Example of MWE considering aforementioned is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \footnotesize
    \centering
%    \sisetup{
\caption{Different datasets with its sizes, types, ADF test, and compression ratio. }
\label{tabadf}
   \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                colsep  = 3pt,
                colspec = {*{3}{Q[c]} 
                                Q[c, si={table-format=-3.3}]
                                Q[c, si={table-format=-1.2e-2}]
                                c Q[c, si={table-format=-2.1}]
                           *{2}{c Q[c, si={table-format=-1.3}]}
                                X[c]
                                X[c, si={table-format=2.2}]
                          },
                row{1}  = {guard}              
                }
Dataset 
    & {Data\\ type} 
        & {Dataset\\ size}
            &  test   
                & A\_value  
                    & \SetCell[c=6]{}   Critial DATA
                        &   &   &   &   &   & Result
                                                & Comm.   \\
A   & Int 32    
        & 3000
            & -767
                & 5.04E-10
                    & 1\%
                        & -87.7
                            & 5\%
                                &-2.864
                                    & 10\%
                                        & -1.518
                                            & Stat\_da
                                                & 14.72     \\
B   & Int 32    
        & 4000  
            & -34.304 
                & 3.94e-13
                    & 1\% 
                        &  -3.4 
                            &   &   &   &   &   &        \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}    
\end{document}
```

[image]